# Determining equivalence classes

Tags: proof-writing, equivalence-relations

[image]

I have done (a), pretty straight forward. I understand an equivalence class as all the elements in the domain that map to the same result in the co-domain. For example in (mod 3), [|0|] would be the same as [|3|] ect.

However I am a little confused in the notaiton here. The relation R clearly defines two coordinate pairs? I am rather confused on how to proceed with (b).

Any help/suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting into our definitions, we have:
\begin{align*}
[(1, 0)]
&= \{(m, n) \in \mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0\mid ((m, n), (1, 0)) \in R\} \\
&= \{(m, n) \in \mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0  \mid m + 0 = n + 1\} \\
&= \{(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), \ldots\}
\end{align*}
Interpreting this graphically, $[(1, 0)]$ is the set of all lattice points in the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane that are on the line $y = x - 1$. The equivalence classes partition these lattice points by grouping them together along parallel lines of slope $1$.